# applicationWillTerminate will called if any crash happens?

Tags: ios

Is it any possibility `applicationWillTerminate` will get called if any crash happens? EXC_BAD_ACCESS will definitely prevent calling `applicationWillTerminate`, but what about other type of crashes?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221573/when-an-app-crashes-does-either-the-applicationwillterminate-or-applicationdi

Answer (score 0):

In any case `applicationWillTerminate` will not called because app crash means something weird/unexpected happened so no delegates get called.